# pandas dataframe group by next occurance of column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Below is my dataframe

```
     info        date       time      file            msg
0   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:10:10:  view.py:          phone   
1   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:10:10:  view.py:         asdasd   
2   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:10:43:  view.py:  contact start   
3   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:10:43:  view.py:    contact end   
4   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:11:36:  view.py:      app start   
5   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:11:36:  view.py:     busy start   
6   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:12:08:  view.py:       busy end   
7   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:12:08:  view.py:    contact end   
8   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:12:08:  view.py:        app end
9   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:12:08:  view.py:          phone
7   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:12:08:  view.py:    contact end
```

I want to split this dataframe into multiple dataframes based on value in `msg` column.
my dataframe should look something like this if i want to split by "phone"   as the value:

df1:

```
     info        date       time      file            msg
0   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:10:10:  view.py:          phone   
1   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:10:10:  view.py:         asdasd   
2   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:10:43:  view.py:  contact start   
3   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:10:43:  view.py:    contact end   
4   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:11:36:  view.py:      app start   
5   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:11:36:  view.py:     busy start   
6   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:12:08:  view.py:       busy end   
7   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:12:08:  view.py:    contact end   
8   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:12:08:  view.py:        app end
```

df2:

```
 info        date       time      file            msg
9   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:12:08:  view.py:          phone
7   INFO:  2018-09-12  16:12:08:  view.py:    contact end
```

Comment: `s = df.groupby(df.msg.eq('phone').cumsum())`, I'll find a dupe for you

Comment: thanks @user3483203

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary for a variable number of related variables. Here you can combine with `GroupBy` + `cumsum`:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['msg'].eq('phone').cumsum())))
```

Then access your dataframes via `d[1]`, `d[2]`, ..., `d[n]`.

Result:

```
{1:  info        date       time      file           msg
 0  INFO:  2018-09-12  16:10:10:  view.py:         phone
 1  INFO:  2018-09-12  16:10:10:  view.py:        asdasd
 2  INFO:  2018-09-12  16:10:43:  view.py:  contactstart
 3  INFO:  2018-09-12  16:10:43:  view.py:    contactend
 4  INFO:  2018-09-12  16:11:36:  view.py:      appstart
 5  INFO:  2018-09-12  16:11:36:  view.py:     busystart
 6  INFO:  2018-09-12  16:12:08:  view.py:       busyend
 7  INFO:  2018-09-12  16:12:08:  view.py:    contactend
 8  INFO:  2018-09-12  16:12:08:  view.py:        append,

 2:  info        date       time      file         msg
 9  INFO:  2018-09-12  16:12:08:  view.py:       phone
 7  INFO:  2018-09-12  16:12:08:  view.py:  contactend}
```